# Accessing OLE object using java

Tags: java, sql, database, ole

I'm working on one application where I have to read the table from the access database. Can anyone tell me how to read the "Ole-object" field from the table?
This field contains some images and I need to read the images and store in some database. But how do I read it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice write up here with source code and examples provided: http://www.douglaspasqua.com/2013/01/24/java-remove-ole-headers-from-images-stored-as-ole-objects-in-access-database/